# How to send images from ionic application to Ruby on Rails webapi that contains paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework, paperclip

```
def create

    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)

    if @activity.save
      respond_to do |format|
       format.js 
      end
    end
end


def activity_params
  params.require(:activity).permit(:title, :message, :activity_type, :allow_comment, :classroom_id, :school_user_id, :image)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use js libraries which are compatible with angularjs, for example:

- [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)
- [angular-file-upload](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/)
- [jQuery-File-Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use base64 upload